# pandas MultiIndex on columns select columns from level 0 (outside) as well as level 1 (inside)

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, multi-index, percentile

Using a dummy dataframe of:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-03'], 'group':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'bar':[1,2,3, 4, 1,2,3, 4], 'baz':[3,4,5, 6, 3,4,5, 6]})
df = df.groupby(['dt', 'group']).describe()
```

[image: -ind]

I.e. I want to be able to select `df[['dt', 'group', ('bar', '25%'), , ('bar', '25%'), , ('bar', '25%')]]`.

How can I perform this multi level selection?

My final goal is to be able to plot the percentiles per category over time where each category describes a color:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
sns.lineplot(data=df.reset_index()['baz'][['25%', '50%', '75%']], hue='group')
```

However, in the remaining dataframe no information regarding group is left.

Comment: Something like `df["bar"].filter(like="%")`?

Comment: @HenryYik's suggestion is very succinct ... i think u should post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another way to skin the cat:

```
print (df["bar"].filter(like="%"))

                  25%  50%  75%
dt         group               
2020-01-01 a      1.0  1.0  1.0
2020-01-02 a      2.0  2.0  2.0
2020-01-03 b      3.0  3.5  4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

not sure if this is what you are after :

```
 #assigned outcome to a different variable
 res = df.groupby(['dt', 'group']).describe()

#create a slicer, makes it easier to slice the multiIndex
idx = pd.IndexSlice

res.loc[idx[:],idx['bar',['25%','50%','75%']]]
```

you could use this to achieve the same result

```
res.loc(axis=1)['bar',['25%','50%','75%']]


                        bar
                25% 50% 75%
   dt   group           
2020-01-01  a   1.0 1.0 1.0
2020-01-02  a   2.0 2.0 2.0
2020-01-03  b   3.0 3.5 4.0
```

or cross sectional slicing :

```
res.xs('bar',level=0,axis=1).filter(['25%','50%','75%'])

                25% 50% 75%
   dt   group           
2020-01-01  a   1.0 1.0 1.0
2020-01-02  a   2.0 2.0 2.0
2020-01-03  b   3.0 3.5 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> I.e. I want to be able to select `df[['dt', 'group', ('bar', '25%'), , ('bar', '25%'), , ('bar', '25%')]]`.

You can do the following:

```
df.reset_index()[[('dt', ""), ('group', ""), ('bar', '25%'), ('bar', '50%')]]
```

Output:

```
           dt group  bar     
                     25%  50%
0  2020-01-01     a  1.0  1.0
1  2020-01-02     a  2.0  2.0
2  2020-01-03     b  3.0  3.5
```

As for the graph, it seems to me like you're trying to make a plot which has 4 dimensions... (x->dt, y->dataframe values, hue->corresponding to each group, and then you have each percentile column e.g. `('bar', '25%')`, `('bar', '50%')`). It's not clear how you want to distinguish the `('bar', '25%')` from `('bar', '50%')` in the plot. Perhaps you're anticipating 6 separate plots (3 percentiles * 2 columns [bar, baz]) in which case maybe this is helpful:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df.reset_index(), x="dt", y=("bar", '25%'), hue='group')
```

[image]

Comment: though this can only plot a single line i.e. 25, not 50 or 75.